# how to write a kubernetes manifest file cause there is no details to explan the parameters?

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed `kubernetes` 1.5 cluster on the aws, when I want to deploy a `LNMP` stack on the k8s cluster, but I find that it's difficult to wirte the `manifest` file, I can't find any examples on k8s official docs. so ,is there any detailed list of `manifest` parameters and also explan what the parameters meanings?

sorry for my poor english, hope somebody can help me ,thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a full reference on their website:

- k8s.io -> Documentation -> Reference -> Select your "Kubernetes API Versions"
- For 1.10: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/

Unfortunately this is hard to read for a beginner. Also, there are many examples on the GitHub repo:

- For 1.9: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.9/examples
- Since 1.10: https://github.com/kubernetes/examples

Comment: I updated the first link. The seconds one still links to some examples as expected.

Comment: Sadly both links are dead.